# What is the right way to add .htaccess file in wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, php-7

I am thinking of adding the .htaccess file in my website which is a wordpress website, according to my research it can optimize the speed of the website by disabling the hotlinking and other stuff.

I want to add it but I am not so sure because I know it from other websites I worked with it can come with errors and I don't understand how wordpress communicate with .htaccess file.

this is the code that i want to add.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?sparringmind.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?feeds2.feedburner.com/sparringmind [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]
```

Wordpress can be trick after adding this file it can trigger more errors and cause me a headache.. I want to know if with this code alone is it safe for me to just add that file on my root file and hope it will just do the job or there are some more configurations I need to run?

Thanks

Comment: Wordpress already relies on a `.htaccess`, for example for the url rewriting that it needs internally to find posts based on the slug, so you should modify the existant, if you replace it, Wordpress won't work well anymore, or not at all

Comment: Is it maybe hidden in my cPanel because I can not find it at all.

Comment: Can you write down what type of errors you are getting it?

Comment: It should be at the root path, where the folders "wp-admin", "wp-content" etc are. It's possible that cPanel doesn't see the files starting with a ".", I don't remember well, haven't used it for ages. If the case, try with FTP, but don't forget to save the original .htaccess file in case you break your site with your changes

Comment: @Jinesh I haven't uploaded the file yet I was afraid of stuff like what Kaddath is talking about only to find out that its already there and give me headache with errors, I will try to connect FillZilla and check if the file is there coz Its not there when I check the cPanel now.

Comment: In asking here I am trying to understand it, I am investigating here i don't understand your comment isn't this page suppose to assist in those sort  of things ? I know the functionalities of the file but differs from what you are working on.

Comment: @ManezaF8  By default cpanel hide the .htaccess. If you use Filezila then it will show .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you @Jinesh I will  try to local it when I get home.

Comment: Okay If you not found then please contact me I can help you.

Comment: Thank you very much, please upvote if my question makes sense and can be helpful to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following steps

1. Enable  **View hidden files** on the server
2. Navigate to the **public_html**
3. Back-up the current **.htaccess**
4. Import new settings

**Troubleshooting**

- 304 Forbidden -  check permissions
- For other issues check the **error_log** on the server

Comment: I just did all that Thanks.